# How to wrap consecutive setInterval() in a forever loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I was trying to implement a function, which is supposed to post measurement A every 5 sec for 10 times, and then post measurement B every 5 sec for a random amounts of time. And I want repeat this function forever as I was trying to implement a fake agent.

So I had the code:

```
let intervalId = null, repeat = 0;
while (true) {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (repeat < 5) {
        // post measurement A
        repeat += 1;
      }
      else {
        clearInterval(intervalId)
      }
    }, 1000);

    repeat = 0;
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (repeat < Math.floor(Math.random() * 11)) {
        // post measurement B
        repeat += 1;
      }
      else {
        clearInterval(intervalId)
      }
    }, 1000);
}
```

The two `setInterval()` function didn't happen consecutively as I expected, instead they happened at the same time. And the `while (true)` loop seems not behave as expected either. I'm just wondering is there any way to get around with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: well while loop is not going to be what you want and what that code is actually doing is creating an ungodly number of intervals.

Comment: Do you want to post the measurement A 10 times and after it gets posted 10 times post measurement of B every 5 second for some random period and after the random period ends repeat the process ?

Comment: Your first set will run every sec for 5 times. `setInterval` just sets up a timer that runs the function every x milliseconds, and then returns the id of the timer. it doesn't wait until all of the intervals are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two `function`,  one is `doA()` and one is `doB()`.

Start with `doA()`, count the number of time `//do A` is called, when it reached `10`, `clearInterval` and call `doB()`.

In `doB()`, set the `min` and `max` time it should be called, then when it reached `randTime` `clearInterval` and `doA()`

```
function doA() {

  let count = 0;
  const a = setInterval(() => {
    //do A
    console.log('do A');
    count += 1;
    if (count === 10) {
      clearInterval(a);
      doB();
    }
  }, 5000/10);

}
function doB() {
  // set your min and max for B
  const minTime = 1;
  const maxTime = 10;
  const randTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxTime - minTime + 1)) + minTime;
  let count = 0;
  const b = setInterval(() => {
    // do B
    console.log(randTime);
    console.log('do B');
    count += 1;
    if (count === randTime) {
      clearInterval(b);
      doA();
    }
  }, 5000 / randTime);
}
doA();
```

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment... I didn't read the code carefully. Thank you very much this answer solved my problem! I learnt a smart trick haha xD

Answer (score 1):

Working on top of your code, first thing first, remove infinite `while` loop. It will run endlessly in synchronous fashion while `setInterval` is asynchronous. `repeat` value will be far ahead before you do `repeat += 1`.

Second, break them down in function so they have their own closure for `intervalId` and `repeat` value.

```js
function intervalA () {
  let intervalId = null
  let repeat = 0
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (repeat < 5) {
      console.log(new Date(), 'A')
      // post measurement A
      repeat += 1; // increment repeat in callback. 
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(intervalId); // done with interval, clear the interval
      intervalB(); // and start interval B
    }
  }, 1000)
}

function intervalB () {
  let repeat = 0
  let randomEnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) // calculate when it should end.
  let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (repeat < randomEnd) {
      console.log(new Date(), 'B will finish in', randomEnd, 'times') 
      repeat += 1
    }
    else {
      clearInterval(intervalId) // clear the interval once done
    }
  }, 1000)
}

intervalA(); //start with interval A
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the intervals are being set at once, synchronously, at the start of your script and during every `while` thereafter. It would probably be clearer if you only a single interval, with a variable that indicated which measurement to run, and change that variable every random-nth iteration:

```js
const getRandomRepeats = () => Math.ceil(Math.random() * 11)
let repeatsRemaining = getRandomRepeats();;
let measureA = true;
setInterval(() => {
  repeatsRemaining--;
  if (repeatsRemaining === 0) {
    repeatsRemaining = getRandomRepeats();
    measureA = !measureA;
  }
  console.log('repeats remaining: ' + repeatsRemaining);
  if (measureA) {
    console.log('posting a');
  } else {
    console.log('posting b');
  }
}, 1000);
```